# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I have 2 classes `Employe(id,Nom,solde...)` and `Conge(id,duree,...)`
I use Annotation and in my test class I put this code to update the "solde" of de employee:

```
Employe p=new Employe();
        p.getSolde();
        p.setSolde(sol.sold(17,2));
        da.updateEmploye(p);
```

but I have an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The
>   given object has a null identifier: metier.Employe

Comment: Paste Employee class definition.

Comment: How is hibernate supposed to know what you want to update? Load the employe from the database and you'll be able to update it.
"new Employe()" is not in the database and therefore you cannot update it

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException` is when you try to save an object without saving his dependencies.

When you have an Entity `A` which contain an Entity `B`, you should create the Entity `B` **before** you can create the Entity `A`.

```
B b = new B();
session.save(b);
A a = new A();
a.setB(b);
session.save(a);
```

Or you can also use [Cascade](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) to indicate to hibernate to save `B` when saving `A`