# Session.save throwing TransientObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities called **student** and **course** with **ManyToMany** **relationship**. As I read in [this](https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example) article that we can call the save method for saving the related entities within the transaction or it will get saved once the session is flushed. I also understand the [typical cascading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865249/exception-in-thread-main-org-hibernate-transientobjectexception) that causes this exception but here I have taken care of it as well, but still **I am getting the TransientObjectException on calling the save method while the persist method works just fine**. Can some one please explain whats happening here?

Here is my code:

**SaveVsPersistTest.java**

```
public class SaveVsPersistTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create session factory object 
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Course.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Student student = new Student("Gopal");

        Course course1 = new Course("Java");
        Course course2 = new Course("C++");

        student.addCourse(course1);
        student.addCourse(course2);

        session.save(student);

        transaction.commit();
        session.flush();
    }

}
```

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="student_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="student_course",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="student_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id")})
    private List<Course> courseList;

    public void addCourse(Course tempcourse) {
        if(courseList == null){
            courseList= new ArrayList<>();
        }
        courseList.add(tempcourse);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourseList() {
        return courseList;
    }

    public void setCourseList(List<Course> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", courseList=" + courseList + "]";
    }

}
```

**Course.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class Course {

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String courseTitle) {
        super();
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
    }



    @Id
    @Column(name="course_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="course_title")
    private String courseTitle;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="student_course",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="student_id")})
    private List<Student> StudentList;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCourseTitle() {
        return courseTitle;
    }

    public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle) {
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return StudentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        StudentList = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", courseTitle=" + courseTitle + ", StudentList=" + StudentList + "]";
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: manytomany.demo.Course
```

Comment: try to add Student to course before saving

Comment: Tried!! but now getting the same exception for Student object:

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: manytomany.demo.Student

Comment: have you tried saving `course1`and `course2` before `student`?

Comment: yeah, I tried that and this ways it's working fine but isn't it should save the related entities automatically within the transaction boundary without waiting for me to call save explicitly?

Comment: Doc says that `save()` executes inmediately not when flushing the transaction. That is related for sure

Comment: yes... but it saves the related entities also when you flush the session without the need to save them explicitly as mentioned here-

https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example

Comment: Sorry but this seems to be Hibernate specific and not related to JPA. Perhaps the JPA tag needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others Suggested you can call session.save on all the related entities explicitly or you can either go with the Hibernate Specific [@Cascade](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html) Annotation as shown below.

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
```

The caveat in using `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` on any association is that you will have all your child objects(or rows in the table) removed once you call delete on the parent objects. So be a bit cautious about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined Cascade modes for persist and merge but for save you have to declare cascade=ALL or save the related entities manually:

`cascade=CascadeType.ALL`

Answer (score 0):

You should try instead of

> session.save()

use

> session.persist()

Comment: I already mentioned before that persist() is working fine. I want to know why not save()?

Comment: I think I should have highlighted it in the question... anyway thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It works for me

```
Student s = new Student();
       s.setName("Gopal");
Course c1 = new Course();
       c1.setCourseTitle("courseTitle1");   
Course c2 = new Course();
       c2.setCourseTitle("courseTitle2");

// adding courses to student entity
 s. getCourseList().add(c1);
 s. getCourseList().add(c2);


// adding a student to courses.
 c1.getStudentList().add(s);
 c2.getStudentList().add(s);


 // saving all entities to DB.
     session.save(s);
     session.save(c1);
     session.save(c2);    

    transaction.commit();
    session.flush();
```

Comment: I already tried this as I have mentioned it in the comments above.

Comment: use cascade=CascadeType.ALL in your Student class courseList field.